# Creating abnormal database queries with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a project where I may not alter the database in any way (unfortunately). I have started the project using Entity Framework and this has worked for the first few objects that I need. Now I have come across two scenarios that I am not sure how to accommodate.

- Tables without a primary key defined.
- Tables using the suffix of the table name as a field.

For the first, I get an error about reviewing my schema and uncommenting the proper area of the edmx file. The table has a field that acts as primary key but is not designated as not null and does not have a primary key created for it.

For the second, there are several tables with names like `order1`, `order2`, `order3` etc where the table that needs to be accessed would be a parameter of my access methods.

My thought is that it would be simplest to just manually write the SQL and bind the data to models. If I go that route would I even use EF or do I just create a new database connection? what would be the 'proper' way to go about that?

Comment: You have a database with design issues, including lack of various properties required by EF, and you aren't allowed to change them. Don't use EF. But also if you can, communicate this to whoever is managing the database side.

Comment: Yes I will communicate it with them. Would it be problematic to use EF with the properly designed tables and something else for the rest?

Comment: I'm not sure but generally speaking if you have _two_ types of accessing data, that makes thinks confusing when you have to maintain the system. Any inconsistency causes confusion when the system is in production. I know that EF does a lot of 'autocoding' for you and makes LINQ easier but that's about it.

Comment: You can always mark a property as primary key in the edmx designer, even if it isn't that in the database. For going from SQL to one of the `order` entities you can also use EF, but then you don't have change tracking.